# Can a JavaScript SPA launch executables installed on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, vue.js

**Context**

We have an application that is written in .NET and runs on a Citrix server. This app consists of shortcuts to external tools (like: DameWare, VNC viewer, mtsc.exe, msra.nexe, ...) that are installed on the server. The user fills in a hostname in the app and the external tool is started after clicking its button with the hostname as a parameter, so a remote connection to the client is set up.

**Goal**

The goal here is to rewrite this application to have it accessible in through am internal website. So Citrix is no longer required.

**idea**

The idea is to use node.js to create the API. This API will be used to add new tools that are installed on the server, launch executables on the server with the arguments from the input box on the website, ...

This will allow us to install all these remote connection tools on one server and have them used by our service desk agents from their web browsers.

**Question**

Is it possible for an SPA, that is created by say Vue.js, to launch an application installed on the server and open it on the users's PC?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I couldn't find any information about this somewhere.

In [a reply to this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754772/execute-a-application-on-the-server-using-javascript) it was said that the API can then launch an executable, but can it also display the GUI from say VNC Viewer on the client PC?

Comment: No, you can't execute any application installed on the server at the client PC (unless you download it automatically there).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

https://github.com/citronneur/mstsc.js/blob/master/README.md

You wont be able to launch programs direct from the browser, as the code there is all sandboxed to prevent that kind of thing.

But you can have an api running with full permissions to launch programs which a web page can call.

You difficulty is then in connecting the input/output of the program with the webpage.

But presumably you have solved many of these problems already in your .net app.

However, I believe citrix already has a web client out of the box, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: _"citrix "_ Eeek!

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. But we have different tools that are used in the company and I would like to support them. So maybe downloading them first on the client as suggested in the comments and then launching the local installation would be a better idea.